# Can you wire a 120 volt receptacle off a 240 volt plug?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, code-compliance, range, canada

I want an over-the-range microwave, but my circuit panel is maxed out, so it can't be on its own circuit, and it would be a headache to run a new wire there anyways.

My stove has two 120 volt plugs on the top of it. I can save some headache by just pluging it into the stove, only thing is I'll have a cable hanging down by the backsplash all the time...

I'm wonding if I could save myself some hassle by running a wire from the 240volt range receptacle to a new 120volt receptacle for the microwave.

I know it would work: just nut the new wire onto one of the two 120 volt legs for the stove. My only concern is that it's a 40 amp circuit, so I'd either have figure out how to protect the wire with some kind of a local breaker (similar to the 15amp breakers on the plugs on the stove) or I'd probably have to run 8AWG up the wall to my new 120volt receptacle.

Buying 6ft of 8AWG and a proper box seems like the best, cheapest and easiest option compared to swapping out my whole panel and figuring out how to get a new run of wire up there. I'm just wondering if it's allowed?

Comment: Do you have a fridge-sized space in your kitchen (or across the wall from it) that you can guarantee is clear of stuff?

Comment: It sucks to be out of panel spaces, but maybe address that with a subpanel. You don't need to replace the whole main panel, which is a huge and prohibitive job, that just sounds like defeatist talk.  Putting a 15A microwave on a 40A circuit is *dangerous!*   At least put it on a kitchen countertop recep circuit, that violates Code too but at least it won't kill you.

Comment: @threephaseeel explain?

Comment: @harper  - reinstate monica if its dangerous could you provide an answer as to why?

Comment: @ShemSeger -- basically, I'm asking if you have a space that's clear enough that you can put a subpanel in/near the kitchen

Comment: Shem there are allowances for “Taps” off the oven circuit but hard wiring is required. Code prohibits corded devices like your microwave from being attached to anything other than a 15 or 20 amp circuit because the wiring can not handle a fault beyond 20 amps. This could cause a fire if more current is available. An over the range is built in so using a counter top receptacle or the one on the stove would violate code in the US.

Comment: Bad idea.  People asking "why" usually only have one goal: to outsmart it.  This tends to lead to certain cognitive biases. There's usually more than one good reason.  If you want to be a Code scofflaw, then just be one... that's between you, your insurance company and your mortgage lender. And the D.A. if anyone gets hurt.

Comment: Could one wire a tap off the range circuit to a fused disconnect switch and then wire from the output of that to a regular 20A socket?

Comment: @PeterGreen -- the issue with that idea is that North American fused switches (safety switches) generally don't play nice with being mounted in finished walls, and box cover units are only suited for supplemental overcurrent protection, not protecting a tap (you also get into branch vs feeder debates and clear working space issues that way)

Comment: @ShemSeger -- can you get us information about where space is available for a subpanel please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The only space would be inside the cabinet over the stove and microwave where the receptacle for the microwave would go.

Comment: @ShemSeger -- is running a cable to another location an option? Also, can you post photos of your electrical panel please, including any labeling on the inside of the door, and of the inside of the box for the range receptacle as well?